# Jest - TypeError: app.address is not a function for router

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, jestjs, supertest

My `app.js` is as follows...

```
require('dotenv').config();
const koa = require('koa');
const router = require('./routes/src').default;
const koaBody = require('koa-body');

const app = new koa();
app.use(koaBody({ multipart: true }));

app.use(router());

app.listen(process.env.PORT);

module.exports = app;
```

And I am combining the routes in `routes/scr/index.js`...

```
const combineRouters = require('koa-combine-routers');
const Router = require('koa-router');
const service = require('../../services/index').default;

const router = new Router({ prefix: '/api' });

router.post('/retrieve', service);

const routers = combineRouters(
  router
);

module.exports.default = routers;
```

Now I want to test the following post request using `jest`. I tried the following...

```
const request = require('supertest');
const route = require('../src/index'); // routes/scr/index.js

test('Hello world works', async () => {
  const payload = {
    test: ''
  };
  try {
    const response = await request(route).post('/api/retrieve').send(payload);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
});
```

For some reason I get the following `supertest` error...

> TypeError: app.address is not a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by defining my server as so...

```
const supertest = require('supertest');
const http = require('http');
const app = require('../../app');

const request = supertest(http.createServer(app.callback()));
...
```